# R - replace repeated element in a data frame

Tags: r, database, replace

I have a dataset, called tweets, like this:

```
     V1        V2         V3  

1    pos       text1      text4

2    neg       text2      text1

3    neu       text3      text5
```

In V2 there are 3424 obs, while in V3 1000 obs. These obs are Tweets imported from a .txt file. 
What I want is something like this:

```
     V1        V2         V3  

1    pos          NA      text4

2    neg       text2      text1

3    neu       text3      text5
```

So, if an element in V2 is the same as an element in V3, the element in V2 must be replaced with NA.

I tryed to use this code:

```
x <- "N/A" 
for(i in 1:1000){ 
  for(l in 1:3424){
    if(full_corpus[i,3] == (full_corpus[l,2])){
    replace(full_corpus,l,x)
}}}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, and i don't know really well how "replace" works.

I receive this error message:

```
  Error in Ops.factor(full_corpus[i, 3], (full_corpus[l, 2])) : 
    level sets of factors are different
```

How can i do this? 
I'm sorry but I started using R, and coding in general, this year in University and I still have a lot o difficulties in this field.

I tryed also this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(textA = ifelse(textA %in% textB, NA, textA) )
```

But it doesn't work. I get

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information
```

and R crashes. I Tryed to reinstall the package dplyr package but I have the same result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[which(df$V2 %in% df$V3),]$V2 <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the first error you provided in the post. 
I assume that while reading your data R transformed `V2` and `V3` to `factors`.
This is way you get the error. Because `NA` is not a `Level` in this `factors`.

But thanks to being `factors` Live got a little easier:
you can compare the `levels` of `V2` and `V3` and remove the `levels` with `NA`, which occur in both vectors, so you do not need to loop over the entire data.

So `duplicates <- match(levels(V2),levels(V3))` gives you the position of the duplicated `levels` in `V2`

and then you can remove them just by:

```
levels(V2)[duplicates] <- NA
```